# Describe listener rule count using lambda boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-application-load-balancer

I just used below code on Lambda function and length function to calculate listner rules. However it always return the value as 2 even ALB has more than 20 rules.

```
import json
import boto3
    
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('elbv2')
    response1 = client.describe_listeners(
    ListenerArns=[
        'arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-west-2:account_id:listener/app/my_load_balancer_listener',
         ],
    )
    tot = len(response1)
    return response1
```

Get the output like this.

```
Response as 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The get the rules, you should use [describe_rules](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/elbv2.html#ElasticLoadBalancingv2.Client.describe_rules):

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('elbv2')
    response1 = client.describe_rules(
    ListenerArn='arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-west-2:account_id:listener/app/my_load_balancer_listener',
    )
    tot = len(response1['Rules'])
    return tot
```